# AS3 Silent email send

Tags: string, actionscript-3, email, mobile

I'm developing an actionscript 3 app that needs to be able to send an email whilst running, but without requesting the user's consent. The idea is that the user gives consent when the app opens, but not at any other time whilst the app is running.

What is the best way for me to do this. Ideally using AS3, but embedding other code is okay if need be.

The email is to contain a string from the AS3.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the user's consent is the problem here (at least not for the developer ;) ).

The problem is, however, that Flash/AS3 simply cannot send emails natively. You will have to work with a server that does that. Or the user's native email client.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364958/how-to-make-a-button-send-an-email-using-as3-automatically), this question is not unknown.

Comment: you can "send" email from flash (with a SMTP server) : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27

Comment: Actually, no. You can call/use a SMTP server from Flash, which then sends the email. Flash does NOT send the email.

Comment: agree, that's why i put " around "send" :)

Answer (score 0):

There are already some really good AS3 libraries out there that do this for you:

http://www.warmforestflash.com/blog/2009/06/flash-as3-contact-form-using-php/

You do not need user's consent other than generating an event to send an email.